# Creating a query that converts "chained" ids to "grouped" ids

Tags: mysql

I request anyone to help me title this question better, I am unsure on how to call it. Perhaps someone will have an idea after they read the question below:

So I have a set of players and their groups stored in MySQL. In the DB, due to legacy reasons they are stored in a strange manner (like a chain), as shown below:

```
Player_Id     New_Group
100           1
101           0
102           0
103           0
104           1
105           0
106           0
107           0
108           0
```

So here basically PlayerId 100 has New_Group set as 1. So he is at the start of a new group. Now all the players after him since they have New_Group as 0, fall into his group. When we get to 104, a new group starts.

What I want to do is to write a query which will give result like so:

```
Player_Id     Group_Id
100           1
101           1
102           1
103           1
104           2
105           2
106           2
107           2
108           2
```

You get the idea...I am trying to convert the New_Group logic into something that just generates pseudo-group-Ids for the players.

However it is beyond my SQL skills to do this. If any SQL Guru can help me that would be AWESOME. I use MySQL.

Comment: Does the player id always ascend down the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How's this?

```
SET @group = 0;
SELECT Player_Id, IF(New_Group, @group:=@group + 1, @group) AS Group_Id
FROM [table]
ORDER BY Player_Id;
```

Comment: Thought about that. Wasn't sure original was ordered, but I'll add.

Comment: If it ain't 'ordered' then the problem is essentially insoluble.

Comment: Wouldn't it process each row as it occurs, and possibly New_Group was entered correctly but with Player_Id unordered? Obviously not a good way to do it.

Comment: Tables in relational databases represent unordered sets. 'As it occurs' has no meaning in this context.

Comment: Thank you. This worked. Do you know how I could remove records if the Group_Id is zero (It represents players not belonging to any group). I have posted a question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43811493/remove-record-if-a-computed-field-is-0-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT player_id
     , CASE WHEN new_group = 1 THEN @i:=@i+1 ELSE @i:=@i END i 
  FROM my_table
     , (SELECT @i:=0) vars 
 ORDER 
    BY player_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have some column in the table that is ascending you could do:

```
select Player_Id, count(select * from [table] t2 where new_group=1 and t2.ascending_row <= t1.ascending_row) from [table] t1
```

In your example above Player_Id could be used for ascending_row as the values are all incrementing. If not you may need to create a temporary table with a column containing the row id and then use that.