# Remove record from result set if a computed field is 0 in Mysql

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have a MySQL query like so:

```sql
SET @group = 0;
SELECT Player_Id, IF(New_Group, @group:=@group + 1, @group) AS Group_Id
FROM [table]
ORDER BY Player_Id;
```

This will give me a list of `Player_Id`s and computed `Group_Id`s (which are numbers). I want to remove any record if the `Group_Id` is `0` in my query result. Can anyone help as my SQL skills are minimal.

Comment: Have you tried implementing that in a DELETE statement rather than a SELECT statement?

Comment: @kojow7 I only want to remove them from the result not from the database

Comment: You can use WHERE

Answer (score 0):

That's should solve your problem:

```
SET @group = 0;
DELETE FROM [TABLE] WHERE Player_Id IN  (
    SELECT u.Player_Id FROM (
        SELECT
            Player_Id,
            IF(New_Group, @group:=@group + 1, @group) AS Group_Id
        FROM [TABLE]
        ORDER BY Player_Id
    ) AS u
    WHERE
        u.Group_Id = 0
);
```